# 4 or more spaces always creates a horizontal text box without wrapping

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

If I type a paragraph into the editor and use four or more spaces to start it (a styling many people use in normal writing - i.e. indenting the first line of a paragraph), then the entire paragraph is converted into a single line horizontally scrolling text box.

Like this :

```
If I type a paragraph into the editor and use four or more spaces to start it (a styling many people use in normal writing - i.e. indenting the first line of a paragraph), then the entire paragraph is converted into a single line horizontally scrolling text box.
```

Now I consider this a bug, as clearly the text should be made to wrap onto new lines if it's width exceeds the display width of the question.

The fact that it also demonstrates that people pay little or no attention to the preview area is just an irritation we can't fix.  But we need automatic wrapping because this is a natural style of typing for many people.

And yes, I know this "feature" is there to facilitate code and similar entry, but it just gets in the way and frankly there's no good reason code can't be wrapped anyway - it's actually how many of us write our code in editors.  Who wants to scroll horizontally across text or code ?

Comment: Wrapping code requires a bunch of additional styles and processing to *indicate* that code has been wrapped. You can't just wrap it and call it good. This is quite an undertaking that is more in-line with implementing a full-fledged new feature, and probably wouldn't happen for some time.

Comment: I don't see how wrapping code is any different from wrapping text.

Comment: @StephenG Some languages, like Python (and Haskell iirc), give line breaks specific meanings. You'd have to at the very least have the little "circular arrow" icon showing that a wrap had taken place, or else code would be read incorrectly. On SO, that would cause problems, especially considering bad indentation/formatting is a cause of many python errors, so we wouldn't know if the bad formatting is on our end or the OP's.

Comment: @StephenG Pro tip: The `<pre>` tag is supported embedded in markup.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Warping the whole website to fit the requirements of some coders seems rather odd.  Most questions are text, not code.  And as for using the pre tag, we could surely use the code tag in markup and surely coders on SO ought to be able to manage that much.

Comment: @StephenG It would be, except for the fact that SO is by far the most used site in the SE network. I wouldn't be surprised if the total user base of SO dwarfs the combined users of every other site. The fact that you're referring to the SO base as "some coders" suggests that you're grossly underestimating the scale and impact of the site. Combine that with the fact that Robert seems to suggest your use is an abuse of spaces in the first place, I'm not sure what you expect. I honestly can't ever think of a time where I've seen a OP manually try to indent a paragraph by 4 spaces.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but that doesn't solve the problem of the OP. They basically ask to get rid of wrapping markdown that starts with 4 spaces in   `<pre><code>` tags and instead add a style for an first-line indent. That could be a feature request.

Comment: @rene Never mind.  It's pretty clear the powers that be have utterly closed minds on the subject.  Apparently all these so-called coders find actual coding mind-numbingly hard.

Comment: Yes, that'll get a positive response. Also, nobody else has a problem with this.  Indenting paragraphs is **so** 5th grade. (that's an inside joke, I'm about the least mature person around here, ask anybody)

Answer (score 8):

*<sup>Warning: Superfluous and somewhat imprecise history below</sup>*

Starting a paragraph with 4-5 spaces was *never* the semantic convention in either written nor online texts.

Typesetting standards in printed text typically dictated how much ***space*** there should be to start a new paragraph (in inches or points, not "spaces"). Even in the age manual typewriters, the use of 4-5 "spaces" was merely coincidental because the early mechanisms advanced mechanically with +/-10 characters per inch being common. A dedicated TAB key soon came on the scene, configured to insert the prerequisite paragraph space.

Fast forward to the the age of computer typesetting (word processing/desktop publishing), where hitting <ENTER> became the norm. You're not expected to type 4 spaces to start a paragraph by design. This is not a computer shortcut — the actual paragraph formatting is supposed to be dictated by style sheets, not manually inserted spaces. Even in *unformatted* online text, two <CR>s are typically used (to create vertical separation) with no character-spaces added.

The widespread adoption of HTLM only solidified this convention. HTML ignores spaces (by design). Later, CSS stylesheets where used to separate paragraphs semantically (and not by inserting spaces).

You can argue whether codeblocks should be auto-wrapped or not, but I suspect that causes more problems than it solves. But using *"4 space to start new paragraph"* is largely gone (and was never actually *correct* to begin with).

I'm afraid you are on the wrong side of history on this.

Comment: *manual typewriters* ... time flies when you're having fun ... I'm getting old ...

Comment: "I'm afraid you are on the wrong side of history on this."  I'm not as obsessed with history as you clearly are.  I am interested in practicality for users.  While the people who design websites these days think that everything revolves around stylesheets and HTML, it does not.  People, you know, ordinary users, do *not* think like that, and I sincerely hope they never do.  Clearly from the very nasty downvoting I'm in a minority on this site.

Comment: @StephenG Your suggestion is predicated on "4 spaces" being common or somehow correct. It's unfortunate you see the time I spent thoughtfully explaining why that is in error as "obsessed". Take care; I'm out.